# Sort a list given a list of indices

Tags: list, scala, sorting

Say I have one unordered list

```
val unsorted = List("third", "second", "fourth", "first")
```

And I have another list that has the indices of the above list in the proper order

```
val ids = List(3, 1, 0, 2)
```

How can I sort `unsorted` using these indices to get this result

```
List("first", "second", "third", "fourth")
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply map the ids onto the unsorted list itself.

```
scala> val sorted = ids map unsorted.toIndexedSeq
sorted: List[String] = List(first, second, third, fourth)
```

Converting `unsorted` to an `IndexedSeq` is not necessary, but as @gzm0 points out below it prevents this operation from being `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Consider calling `toIndexedSeq` on `unsorted` first, otherwise this will be `O(n^2)`.